# Prayer for Energy Shakti?

Tags: shiva, mantras, stotra, parvati, shakti

I'm looking for a **Mantra, stotra, anything which gives Energy/Power** to Perform a Mental Task or Physical Task, preferably on God of Energy, Adi Shakti Parvati Kali or anyone...

**Found BalaAtibala Mantra and Shakti Data Vinayaka Mantra**

also found.. called [Shakti Prapti Mantra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4udFucj9fk)

where does that ... .. Mantra come..reference source

Comment: I know about one such mantra dedicated to Shakti Ganapaty. Search for it on the internet.

Comment: @Rickross [Shakti Ganapati](https://www.astroved.com/astropedia/en/gods/shakti-ganapathi) and can you check if this is (real or fake)[https://www.gurushakti.org.in/169/sadhna/beauty-health/mantra-to-remove-fatigue-quickly]

Comment: The link you gave returned some error. Anyway I will check one book later to find out the exact mantra. But there is no guaranty that it will work. Because mantras usually work only after initiation. But I will tell you the mantra later.

Comment: Is this fake or (real)[https://www.gurushakti.org.in/169/sadhna/beauty-health/mantra-to-remove-fatigue-quickly]]

Comment: No it does not seem to be fake.

Comment: @Rickross Any Mantra? Shakti Ganapaty ?

Comment: Yes I found the follwing one. It's called "Shakti Data Vinayaka Mantra" ( the mantra of Lord Ganesha that gives power/energy" - **Om hrim grim hrim** ... It is said in the book that one has (can) to chant it all the time, even one is on the move etc .. and then it gives energy/power, enthusiasm and fearlessness.

Comment: @Rickross Thanks,, Only that line,, is that a part of verse then I would like to read full.. I found a verse in this [link](https://manasataramgini.wordpress.com/2005/02/19/the-primal-shrine-of-vighnadeva/) related to OoM hrIM grIM hrIM || Is it the verse you were referring .. Are there any Mantra on Parvati.. God of Shakti..

Comment: What I've given is a mantra not a sloka (verse). Just chanting the mantra will do. I can not guaranty anything but when I tried it I felt it really gives some energy.

Comment: I have checked your link. They are giving various mantras for Lord Ganesha. Om Vakratundaya Hum is a famous Ganesh mantra. The last one is the one I have given. It's called Shaktidata Vinayaka mantra. And that whole thing (on the site) is not a verse. They are different mantras given one after another.

Comment: @Rickross Thanks.

Comment: Repeating any standard mantra of any hindu deity will give you energy, but the energy/ojas doesnot manifest because of you not practicing Yama-Niyama like not waking-sleeping proper time, lying, greed, anger, tamsik diet etc., Om is primordial mantra of nature, all mantras manifested from it, hence its used before any mantra.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Does chanting without initiation give bad results or negative effect..or Chanting without initiation gives no result.... If it gives bad result..why would God punish someone for chanting with faith...is there any alternative to initiation.. what about the self initiation process described here [link](https://www.manblunder.com/articlesview/self-initiation-of-mantras)

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Ok.. Understood.. but What about the Self Initiation [Link](https://www.manblunder.com/articlesview/self-initiation-of-mantras) .. is it supported in scripture.

Comment: I don't know whether scriptures say so.  However, in the case of Sri Anandamayi Ma and Sri Ramana Maharshi, they adopted Self initiation.  It is a very rare situation, and not open for all.  @HinduKid

Comment: @srimannarayanakv I already know the importance of initiation,, but for knowledge, can you provide Mantras related to energy..

Comment: You can recite Durga Sapthsathi or Devi Mahatmyam, which contains chAmundA mantra.  According to the tradition, chAmundA mantra will be recited 108 times, alongwith anganyAsa and karanyAsa, in the beginning and at the end.@HinduKid

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Are there any other way of Increasing Energy in other Hindu_Scriptures like Yoga, Pranayama or Ayurveda, or any other scripture..

Comment: @HinduKid: Yes, Yoga, Pranayama or Ayurveda, etc, are some of the ways to increase Energy and concentration.  However, they need to be practiced under the guidance of an expert.  Pranayama, especially, can cause havoc to one's physical health if done in a wrong way. Further, uncontrolled release of ENERGY due to practice of any system without guidance, can create hallucinations, and some times drive one mad.  So take the guidance of an expert.

Comment: @Rickross या देवी सर्वभुतेषु शक्तिरूपेण संस्थिता । नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः ॥ Is this for energy, Are there any other stotra for power.

Comment: Yes that one can be chanted for 10/28/108 times if you have time. That particular verse from Durga Sapatasati is chanted for getting Shakti or power. There are similar verses for Buddhi, Shanti etc. I can't remember now any other Stotra specifically for Shakti. @HinduKid

Answer (score 3):

It is always advisable to take a mantra, containing bIjAksharAs like aim, klim, etc, from an accomplished Guru. An accomplished Guru will be knowing which mantra will suit to one aspirant. There are 2 phases in getting siddhi of a mantra. (1) Priliminary stage, where an accomplished Guru will study the nature of the aspirant and initiates one into appropriate mantra (2) Apart from reciting the mantra, one has to purify oneself internally, or soul purification. The more one becomes purified internally, the better results will be. It takes its own time.

---

The Bala and atibala mantras, which were mentioned in the question content by the OP, were composed by Sage Viswamitra and taught to Sri Rama alone. So initiation into great mantras require great purification of mind like that of Sri Rama. Unless one is qualified, no accomplished Guru will teach such great mantras to everyone in the street.

Even if learnt from somewhere else, the effect will be nothing.

---

Here is an [anecdote on the importance of initiation](https://www.himalayanacademy.com/view/bd_2003-08-15_niyama-9-japa-recitation).

> A minister in a court was summoned to appear before the king. The
>   minister also happened to be a brahmin priest, a kulaguru, empowered
>   to give initiation in the Panchakshara mantra, 'Aum Namah Sivaya'. The
>   king asked the minister to initiate him and the kulaguru said that he
>   would, that he could start preparing the king, right away. The
>   maharajah was impatient and demanded that the minister initiate him
>   immediately, without any preparation.
>
> Of course, the kulaguru objected and told the king that it was not
>   possible, as his tradition required him to only initiate after proper
>   training had been given. The kulaguru explained further that this was
>   a vow he had made to his own Guru, when he was empowered to give
>   initiation. The maharajah replied that he would do the mantra without
>   initiation, unless the kulaguru explained how the mantra worked
>   differently, without initiation. The kulaguru agreed to explain the
>   difference.
>
> The guru then called loudly to the five guards, who were present and
>   told them to arrest the king, because he had demanded initiation
>   without undergoing the necessary preparations that his tradition
>   required. Of course, the guards did not act on his order but instead
>   looked toward the maharajah waiting to be told how to respond.
>
> The king was quite upset at the preposterous order of his minister and
>   shouted to the guards **to arrest the kulaguru**. Of course, the
>   **guards quickly came forward and grabbed the guru and held him tightly**.
>
> The kulaguru smiled and explained his actions by saying that what he
>   said was just answering the king's question. The guru went on to
>   explain that he had spoken the mantra, **"Arrest this man"**.
>
> But, as he had not been prepared for and coronated, and thus empowered
>   as king, the guards did not respond. However, when the Maharajah gave
>   the same mantra, "Arrest this man," because he had been properly
>   prepared and coronated as king, the guards responded. Upon hearing the
>   explanation the maharajah understood the importance of proper
>   preparation and initiation and prostrated at the kulaguru's feet.

---

If the OP wants to do mantra japa, without initiation, it is better to do pArAyana or recitation of Durga Sapthsathi, which contains the mantra with bIjAksharAs.

> ॐ ऐं ह्रीं क्लीं चामुण्डायै विच्चे।

Unless initiated and done in a proper way, this mantra japa will result in nAma japa only and the Devi or Shakti will direct the reciter to a proper Guru for initiation.

Comment: **"Devi or Shakti will direct the reciter to a proper Guru for initiation"** .. Thanks for this hopeful line.

Comment: perfectly said -- *"Devi or Shakti will direct the reciter to a proper Guru for initiation"*

Comment: @srimannarayanakv या देवी सर्वभुतेषु शक्तिरूपेण संस्थिता ।
नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः ॥  Is this for energy, Are there any other stotra for power.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Chanting Mantra requires Initiation, but what if I listen to Mantras 

Comment: @HinduKid: Sravana, listening to  someone else's   recitation, is an accepted way Bhakti